# Are the kernel headers required for anything other than compiling glibc and kernel modules?

Tags: linux-kernel, header-files, glibc

Hope the question is clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. They're required for anything that requires kernel facilities (inotify, V4L2, DRM, FUSE, etc.).